# NameError (uninitialized constant OrdersController::AdressesPacks) HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I make a has_and_belongs_to_many association in my models:

pack.rb

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :adresses
```

adress.rb

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packs
```

In my controller i put this to create the habtm :

```
   @adress = AdressesPacks.create(:adress_id => params[:order],:pack_id => params[:order])
```

but when i execute i get this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant OrdersController::AdressesPacks):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a HABTM relationship it's not necessary to interact with the table that contains the join data. To add an existing Pack to an existing Adress:

```
@adress = Adress.find(params[:order])
@adress.packs << Pack.find(params[:order])
```

If you didn't need the Adress instance, you could simplify the above into a single line:

```
Adress.find(params[:order]).packs << Pack.find(params[:order])
```

Comment: there is a mystype but it's the right answer for me ;)

  Adress.find(params[:order]).packs << Pack.find(params[:order])

Comment: Corrected bracket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use HABTM you have no join model. In other words, there is no `AdressesPacks`-model, at least as long as you haven't created it yourself.

Instead, you create relations by doing stuff like this:

```
@adress.packs << @pack
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the `uninitialized constant` error was happening because one of the models in my HABTM relationship was giving a runtime error upon initialization.  I fixed the runtime error (apparently `attr_accessible` doesn't work out of the box in Rails 4) and it also solved the `uninitialized constant` error.